# How is memory allocation done for char* variables? Does it reallocate itself if further used?

Tags: c

So I have this code,

```
int main() {
char* currentWorkingDirectory = getcwd(NULL, 0);
char* moviesFileDir = currentWorkingDirectory;
char* buyersFileDir = currentWorkingDirectory;
strcat(moviesFileDir, "\\Movies.txt");
strcat(buyersFileDir, "dljasdoihjawuieyawodiujasiodyhawoirasioufgyaisdufghytewdasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasasaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
printf("Directory: %s\n", moviesFileDir);
printf("Directory: %s\n", buyersFileDir);
return 0; }
```

And was wondering how exactly is the memory allocated for these two variables? (moviesFileDir, buyersFileDir), because for example if I do not instantiate them with the value of *currentWorkingDirectory* I will have to use **malloc** to allocate a memory size for the variables, but in this case they already have space alocated since they are a copy of *currentWorkingDirectory*, but from that point onwards, for example when I did the **strcat** cast on them, how did they know how to allocate enough memory for whatever it was concatenated with? If I'm not mistaken, if I would've used malloc from the start and tried to do the same **strcat** on them I would've had to use **realloc** on them with the size of the concatenated string, right?

Sorry if I'm not concise enough but this is my first stackoverflow topic xD

Comment: several c-string library functions **do not** allocate. it's up to you to provide enough memory.

Comment: char * variables are pointers and have a fixed size.

Comment: You must also be aware that both pointers point to the same buffer. You should not expect different output if you print both of them.

Comment: @Gerhardh But the thing is that by printing them I obtain the desired result, which is 2 separate strings derived from the currentWorkinDirectory string + the additional strings that I've concatenated

Comment: @BejinariuPaulCatalin That's because you're just getting lucky. [On Godbolt, your program crashes because you've corrupted memory `malloc` expects not to have been corrupted.](https://godbolt.org/z/aKjeKMrzd)

Comment: Being new to C, it seems a bit exhausting for me creating these new pointers and allocate them each with his line, then doing the strcpy from source to destination for each and repeating for strcat, chaining would've been easier and what I did indeed worked for me but I got stuck wondering why and I was sure that because of the nature of C, what I've just written might be already unsafe, but still I got lazy and tried shortening instead of adding at least 6 lines of code for some not so useful functionality

Comment: Yes, C requires a lot of care and finesse around memory management. No doubt it's exhausting.

Comment: If you print both pointers with `printf("a=&p; b=%p\n", (void*)moviesFileDir, void(*)buyersFileDir);` you should get 2 identical addresses. Therefore I can't really imagine how you might get 2 different strings. Instead you should get the current working directory + both strings you concatenated for each of your `printf` calls. If you really get 2 different strings, that can only be caused by the undefined behaviour you invode that has some visible effect between both calls to `printf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoth [the documentation for `strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat):

> The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character.

In other words, `strcat` does not allocate any memory by itself.

[The documentation for `getcwd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) says

> As an extension to the POSIX.1-2001 standard, glibc's getcwd() allocates the buffer dynamically using malloc(3) if buf is NULL. In this case, the allocated buffer has the length size unless size is zero, when buf is allocated as big as necessary. The caller should free(3) the returned buffer.

In other words, we should assume `currentWorkingDirectory` is exactly as large as it needs to be and none larger, so `strcat`ing into it is Undefined Behavior and will likely scribble onto other memory.

That will either corrupt your program's memory or outright crash it right away (the former case being more insidious and harder to trace).

You should also notice that `char* moviesFileDir = currentWorkingDirectory;` etc. do not take copies.

[Here on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/aKjeKMrzd), your program happily crashes with

> malloc(): corrupted top size

because you've written onto memory you shouldn't have written onto (evidently memory containing `malloc`'s internal state).

---

A safe but somewhat non-efficient implementation that allocates just enough memory (though this example leaks memory since we're not `free()`ing anything we allocate, either directly or indirectly) would be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *currentWorkingDirectory = getcwd(NULL, 0);
  int string_length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s%s", currentWorkingDirectory, "\\Movies.txt", "dljasdoihjawuieyawodiujasio");
  char *buf = malloc(string_length + 1);
  sprintf(buf, "%s%s%s", currentWorkingDirectory, "\\Movies.txt", "dljasdoihjawuieyawodiujasio");
  printf("Directory: %s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

which uses `snprintf()` to first compute how many bytes are required, then allocates that (plus 1 for the trailing NUL), then `sprintf()`s into that new buffer.

Finally, here's a reusable implementation of the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Like sprintf, but allocates just enough memory for the string to format.
 * 
 * The caller must free the returned buffer (which could be NULL if there's a problem).
 */
char *sprintf_alloc(const char *restrict format, ...) {
    char *buf = NULL;
    va_list va;
    // (1) Figure out how much memory to allocate.
    va_start(va, format);
    int string_length = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, va);
    va_end(va);
    if(string_length < 0) return NULL;  // format error?
    // (2) Allocate that much memory.
    buf = malloc(string_length + 1);
    if(buf == NULL) return NULL; // allocation error?
    // (3) Actually format into the buffer.
    va_start(va, format);
    vsprintf(buf, format, va);
    va_end(va);
    return buf;
}

int main() {
  char *currentWorkingDirectory = getcwd(NULL, 0);
  char *buf = sprintf_alloc("%s%s%s", currentWorkingDirectory, "\\Movies.txt", "dljasdoihjawuieyawodiujasio");
  free(currentWorkingDirectory);
  printf("Directory: %s\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but for example in my program, where does that extra memory come from that would've been required for the concatenation? Or is it just because of that "undefined" behavior of the **strcat** ?
Or could it just be that **getcwd** just further reallocated or sort of propagated the allocation?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, and you're just lucky.

Comment: I just realized doing **char* moviesFileDir = currentWorkingDirectory;** was a mistake from the beginning because this thing does not exist in C without doing strcpy, which also requires the memory to be there beforehand... I guess it's just being used to other stuff and the automatism that would've made me realize things a bit faster otherwise :D Anyway, thanks for the help, it shed some light in the dark!

Comment: That was pointed to you in both this answer and @Gerhardh's comment. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Yep, I guess I didn't actually understand at first what all the stuff meant until I made the connections myself